# Access a Workflow's Variables from a method

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I have a *Switch* activity that has an expression of

```
escalateEngine.CheckRules()
```

Where `escalateEngine` is an instance of a class that is passed to the workflow as an argument and `CheckRules()` is a method designed to work out if a problem that the workflow has encountered should be retried or aborted (usually the error is *"ftp server not available"*).

The `CheckRules()` method returns an int that is used by the *Switch* activity to reroute workflow execution.

What I don't see how to do is how I can get `CheckRules()` to change the value of a Variable in the workflow.  It's not an activity so does not have access to `CodeActivityContext`.  At least I don't think it does.

Can anyone offer advice?

I realize I could use `InvokeMethod` to output the value and then run that value into the *Switch* but I was hoping for something neater

Comment: This would seriously break encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that you can't change workflow variables outside of the workflow.

Comment: Well, as already John Saunders pointed out, that would brake encapsulation in a very serious way.